# BLOB and CLOB data type same programs

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee

is it possible to develop a database application to demonstrate storing and retrieving of BLOB (Binary Large Object) and CLOB (Character Large Object) objects using
Front - end : Java, 
Back-end : Oracle

I have installed Netbeans7.3.1 and Oracle 11g

Comment: Yes, it is.  I assume, though, that this isn't your real question.  Assuming you have a specific question, can you post your actual code and ask something specific?

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague- but yes. There are many ways; my preference is to use something like JPA (I use EclipseLink) with your Oracle database. Once you have JPA setup for the database, create an entity an use the @Lob annotation on the field to mark it as a Lob type. Then you can retrieve it from the database and work on it as an object. In the case of Blob you get a byte array back, and Clob comes back as a String.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible. As an entry point you might start here [Oracle JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html)

or maybe here (depending what you want to achieve)
[Oracle Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqst.html#giqsc)